# Read table with comment lines starting with "##"

Tags: r, read.table, vcf-variant-call-format

I'm struggling to read my tables in Variant Call Format (VCF) with R.
Each file has some comment lines starting with `##`, and then the header starting with `#`.

```
## contig=<ID=OTU1431,length=253>
## contig=<ID=OTU915,length=253>
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  /home/sega/data/bwa/reads/0015.2142.fastq.q10sorted.bam
Eubacterium_ruminantium_AB008552    56  .   C   T   228 .   DP=212;AD=0,212;VDB=0;SGB=-0.693147;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,212;MQ=59    GT:PL   1/1:255,255,0
```

How can I read such table without missing a header? 
Using `read.table()` with `comment.char = "##"` returns an error: `"invalid 'comment.char' argument"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to read VCF, you can also just try to use `readVcf` from `VariantAnnotation` in Bioconductor.
https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/VariantAnnotation.html

Otherwise, I can highly recommend `fread` function in `data.table` package.
It allows you to use the `skip` argument to allow it to start importing when a substring has been found.

e.g.

```
fread("test.vcf", skip = "CHROM")
```

should work.

Comment: **fread** function with _skip_ argumernt was really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes VariantAnnotation fails and I think this second suggestion really works quite well for corner case VCFs. One can do whatever is needed to clean the data and then add a %>% Granges() at the end to do overlap analysis, annotation, and merging (after making sure that chr, start, and end come first with a dplyr::select(chr,start,end,dplyr::everything()).